# Having issues finding out how to do A Pyautogui delay

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

So I'm trying to automate my Manga reading and I'm coming into the trouble of finding out how to set a duration for each event. For example if I want it to scroll for 200 seconds then click the next page at X & Y coordinates, how would I go about doing this?

**Note:** I understand how to make pyautogui click. I'm more concerned on figuring out how to make it time delay.

```
import pyautogui


speed = input('how fast should it scroll')
sleepTime = input('how long before next scroll')

pyautogui.time.sleep(3)

 

while 0 < 10:
    pyautogui.moveTo(918, 492, duration=26, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.scroll(int(speed))
    
    pyautogui.time.sleep(int(sleepTime))
    
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [PyAutoGUI docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#fail-safes)

Instead of:

```
pyautogui.time.sleep(3)
```

Do this:

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = 3
```